# How could this algorithm be optimized?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I recently took a online screening test for a position and one of the problems was inserting a 5 at a position that would maximize the value of the given integer. This was my solution but I scored a 50% on correctness and a 50% on performance. I dont really see where I went wrong or how I could improve it, so I would like some insights on how this is the wrong approach.

```js
function insertDigit(num) {
  let neg = num < 0;
  let split = neg ? (num * -1).toString().split('').reverse() : num.toString().split('');
  let digit = 5;
  let i = 0;

  while(split[i] > 5){
      i++;
  }

  split.splice( i, 0, "5" );
  return neg ? split.reverse().join('') : split.join('');
}

console.log( insertDigit(237) );
```

Edit: in this example the input is 237 and the expected output is 5237, if it were -237 the expected output would be -2357

Comment: Converting numbers to a string to perform mathematical expressions on them is typically not as performant as using division and remainder (`/` and `%`) to extract digits. Were you correct with negative numbers? negative numbers are maximized when they are closer to 0.

Comment: @moreON yes, it also works for negative numbers. I believe the reason why the correctness was 50% was because it just timed out and marked as wrong because of it. I tried to think of how I could calculate a number to add to the given number to insert the 5 at the given position, but I could not think up a way

Comment: You would better add an example of an expected input and its output.

Answer (score 1):

```
const ref = 5;

function getModulo(num) {
    let len = num.toString().length;
    let mod = 1
    while(len !== 1)  {
        mod *= 10;
        len -= 1
    }
    return mod
}

function recBigNumForNeg(num) {
    if(parseInt(num/mod) >= ref) {
        return '5' + num;
    }
}

function recBigNumForPos(num, mod) {
    if(num === 0) {
        return ref
    }
    if(parseInt(num/mod) < ref) {
        return '5' + num;
    }
    return '' + parseInt(num/mod) + recBigNumForPos(parseInt(num%mod), parseInt(mod/10))
}

function biggestNumber(num) {
    let mod = getModulo(num)
    if(num < 0) {
        return recBigNumForNeg(-num, mod)
    } else {        
        return recBigNumForPos(num, mod)
    }
}
```

The above code solves your problem, and it doesn't include any string related operations. But it does have couple of problems though.

1. The digits involved in the number should be only from 1 to 9, but it should not include 0. Since this is not mentioned in the question I took the privilege to not include 0.
2. `recBigNumForNeg` is the same method, but just a reversal in logic, so I put it as blank for your exercise.

This is just an alternative approach to the question, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Correctness:

If the input is -237, your function will return 2357 instead of -2357.
This can be easily fixed by changing the return statement to

```
  return neg ? "-" + split.reverse().join('') : split.join('');
```

Performance:

Instead of converting the input to string, I would do MOD and DIV operations to split the input into left and right part and then insert 5 in between. I would do this for all possible positions for 5. Finally, I would pick the maximum value.

Example splitting 237:

```
1st iteration: left=237; right=0   -> num=2375
2nd iteration: left=23;  right=7   -> num=2357
2nd iteration: left=2;   right=37  -> num=2573
2nd iteration: left=0;   right=237 -> num=5237
```

The code:

```
function insertDigit(num) {
  var digit = num > 0 ? 5 : -5;
  var max = num * 10 + digit;
  var digitPos = 1;
  var left = num;
  var right = 0;
  
  while (left != 0) {
    right = num % digitPos;
    left = (num - right) * 10;

    max = Math.max(max, left + digitPos * digit + right)
    digitPos = digitPos * 10;
    }
  
  return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could think is to break out of the loop earlier if split value is less than 5, to save some CPU cycles.

```
function insertDigit2(num) {
  let neg = num < 0;
  let split = neg 
    ? (num * -1).toString().split('').reverse()
    : num.toString().split('');
  
  let digit = 5;
  let i = 0;

  split.every(s => {
    if (s <= 5)
      return false;

    i++;
    return true
  })

  split.splice( i, 0, "5" );
  return neg ? split.reverse().join('') : split.join('');
}

console.log( insertDigit2(237) );
```